# Рубля или рублей?

Tags: согласование, окончания

...в том числе НДС размере 200 341 (двести тысяч триста сорок один) рубля или рублей?

Comment: См. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439557/%d0%a0%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Двухсот тысяч трехсот сорока одного рубля*, так как числительное заканчивается на один.

Comment: Ну хоть бы намёк на аргументацию...

Comment: @shampar этот ответ был дан когда на сайте было пара десятков постоянных пользователя, поэтому зачастую было достаточно лишь авторитета.

Comment: Тем не менее, ссылаться на такой ответ как «правильный» невозможно, формально он такой, но по сути он — ненужный балласт.

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере между формами *рубля* и *рублей* следует выбрать *рубля*, так как существительное должно быть согласовано с числительным *один*. Но допустим также вариант с именительным падежом: в размере 200 341 **рубль**. 
См. [Рубля или рублей? (1)](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439557/%d0%a0%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-1)

Answer (score 0):

Корректно: в размере двухсот тысяч триста сорока одного рубля.

Comment: А какой вопрос задать? Если "в размере каком?", то получается, порядковое числительное.

Comment: Это не порядковые числительные, а количественные.