# 10542 рубля или рублей?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, падежи, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

**В размере 10542 рублей или рубля?**
Как правильно?

Comment: В этот момент Надежда получила серебришко (2500 просмотров). :))

Answer (score 1):

1. Полное предложение отсутствует, поэтому ориентируемся на обычные правила согласования:
   [Долг] **в размере** — чего? Р. п. — десяти тысяч пятисот **сорока двух рублей**.

*Тариф на железнодорожные перевозки пассажиров... устанавливается **в размере 32 рублей.***

2. Подобный вопрос рассматривался на [**Грамоте.ру**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F) (Вопрос № 289687):

Как правильно? Перечислить денежные средства для выплаты дохода в сумме 1001  (одна тысяча один)  рубль или в сумме 1001 (одной тысячи одного) рубля? Итак, после "в сумме" в данном контексте следует употреблять именительный или родительный падеж?

Ответ: **В документах принято использовать именительный падеж**.

*В сумме* = *в размере*, поэтому Вы сами должны сделать выбор падежа в зависимости от контекста.

Вот ещё [пример](https://pasmi.ru/archive/129894/):

*25 октября 2011 года судья (...) вынес решение о частичном удовлетворении исковых требований (...) и взыскал в его пользу (...) денежные средства в размере 205 042 842 (двести пять миллионов сорок две тысячи восемьсот **сорок два**) **рубля***.

Answer (score 0):

Из ответов Грамоты можно сделать вывод, что в обычном тексте действуют общие правила, но в канцелярском стиле с написанием суммы в скобках числительное может ставиться в именительном падеже. ([Подборка ответов](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%A0%D0%86%20%D0%A1%D0%82%D0%A0%C2%B0%D0%A0%C2%B7%D0%A0%D1%98%D0%A0%C2%B5%D0%A1%D0%82%D0%A0%C2%B5).)

> Вопрос № 296787
>    Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как правильно: В размере 10543 рублей ....или рубля? Спасибо.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Правильно: в размере 10543 рублей.
>
> Вопрос № 290237
>   Помогите правильно просклонять числительное, запуталась! Его приговорили к двум тысячам рублям (или рублей) штрафа?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Лучше: к штрафу в размере двух тысяч рублей.

Но

> Вопрос № 245873
>    Добрый день, подскажите правильное написание суммы в тексте договора: "... обязан выплатить сумму в размере 900 рублей (девятьсот, девятисот или девятиста) рублей..."?
>   Спасибо!
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Как правило: в размере 900 (Девятьсот) рублей.
>
> Вопрос № 245873
>   Добрый день, вопрос следующий: как пишется числительное в скобках. Например, сумму, в размере 12 (Двенадцати) рублей или сумму, в размере 12 (Двенадцать) рублей. есть какие-то жесткие правила? или на усмотрение сторон. Заранее спасибо за ответ
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Жестких правил нет, предпочтительно: *в размере 12 (Двенадцать) рублей.*